# Audio not working in openmeeting 4.0.4, on click of start recording test it just gets disabled

Tags: nginx, openmeetings

I installed openmeeting 4.0.4. Audio not working. when I click on start recording test to check setup it's just get disabled.

I checked logs, nothing suspicious or no error in log files.

What may be the issue?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Do you have any Camera/Mic available? have you set up HTTPS?

Comment: Yes camera and mic is available, After selecting that and clicking start recording test it just gets disabled. About https, where I have to set up https?

Comment: Is this issue reproducible with latest version of OM (4.0.8 at the moment)?

Is this reproducible on demo server: https://om.alteametasoft.com/openmeetings?

Comment: Yes. It's working there.

Comment: Can you check if 4.0.8 work at your server?

Comment: but then I have to installed n reconfigure that. Why 4.0.4 not working on another server it is working.

Comment: I am getting "ScopeApplicationAdapter:791 [Thread-124] - [MessageSender] -> 'Unable to send message to  NULL scope' stopStream, java.lang.Object@3ac2f0d1" this error sometimes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately we are not able to support all versions being released, we do support 1 latest (currently 2: 4.0.8 and 5.0.0).

I just noted "nginx" label, are you using nginx as frontend proxy?

Have you checked mail archives https://openmeetings.markmail.org/ to find correct config?

Here is working config for Apache [Apache OpenMeetings 4.0.4 CSRF attack when using apache2 as proxypass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51721771/apache-openmeetings-4-0-4-csrf-attack-when-using-apache2-as-proxypass)

In case you are not using RTMPS you need to disable it is Admin -> Config: `flash.secure` should be `OFF`

https://om.alteametasoft.com/openmeetings/docs/GeneralConfiguration.html

Comment: Yes I am using nginx. My request is going for rtmps instead of rtmp. Which configuration is wrong? I am not using SSL for openeeting. This is my log for port testing start test... rtmps://my_url:8443/om/hibernate